# Formatting ticklabel number error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys

For some reason i cant format the ticknumber and restrain it at the same time, what is wrong?

It repeatedly renders the errors

```
[{
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \\item.\n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 17,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 17,
    "endColumn": 65536
}]
[{
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/at', to which you passed '(yticklabel* cs:1.03,-0.3em)', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.\n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 45,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 45,
    "endColumn": 65536
}]
```

## MWF

```
\documentclass[border={3mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[hyperref]{xcolor} % Options: gray - dark and light

\setlength\textwidth{160mm}

\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfmath,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat  = newest,
    width   = .95\linewidth, % width
    height  = 7cm,           % height
    % Tick Label
    xticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        set thousands separator={\,},
    },
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}

            \addplot[
                domain={-9:-5.5},
                thick,
                samples=2,
            ] { -0.0127*x-0.0483 };

            \addplot[
                mark=*,
                only marks,
            ] coordinates {
                (-9.210340371976182, 0.068)
                (-8.517193191416238, 0.060)
                (-7.600902459542082, 0.048)
                (-6.907755278982137, 0.039)
            };

            \addplot[
                mark=*,
                only marks,
            ] coordinates {
                (-5.298317366548036, 0.036)
                (-4.605170185988091, 0.036)
            };
            
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{center}...\end{center}` does not work in the `standalone` class without further ado. You can either use e.g. `\documentclass[border={3mm},varwidth]{standalone}` or remove the `center` environment.

Comment: As the comment above suggests, the error is not related to the tick formatting. But, how do you expect the x ticks to be formatted?  Since the numbers are smaller than 1000, the setting regarding the thousands separator won't be visible, obviously.

Comment: To simplify the question i removed a bunch of commands, one of which was `\setlength\textwidth{160mm}` maybe that would solve the problem with the `center` environment. After fixing that the error persists tho.
As for the x ticks formatting, this piece code lives within my default settings for pgfplots, might not be used in the example but its default for every graph i draw.

Comment: After your modification, the above comment is still valid: The modified code works, if you remove the `center` environment or add the `varwidth` option to `\documentclass{standalone}`.

Comment: Well the `center` environment is needed, for simplicity it i extracted the code from its origin, but normally it would be enclosed in a `minipage` and them `tcolorbox` environments. I suspect the error lives in `/pgf/number format/.cd`, the second error message points there and removing it the code works. i would like to have control of the typesetting of my axis numbers in the future tho.